# How to manipulate CSS of JupyterLab 3.6.1 for Git section?

Tags: css, jupyter-lab

I am using JupyterLab 3.6.1 and in the section with the GUI for Git I have the following annoying behavior.

[image: annoying behavior]

As you can see there is a scrollbar on the right side which appears if I hover over the button. This makes it difficult to hit the button and sometimes I miss it.

I guess it is some CSS which makes the plus-sing bold or slightly larger on hover. How to fix this?

#### Comment

I made this observation in Chrom 114.0.5735.199. On the latest firefox version I don't see anything like this.

### Update

I found the class which applies the change. There is a transformation on if the icon is active.

```css
.f1q30mbz:active {
    background-color: var(--jp-layout-color3);
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

If I deactivate the transformation, the problem is solved. How can I overwrite this using a local CSS?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add some changes to the `index.css` placed in `lab/api/themes/@jupyterlab/theme-light-extension/index.css`.

In the usecase above it is sufficant to add

```css
.f1q30mbz:active { transform: none; }
```

The changes will be lost if the jupyter lab is build again.